# material-ui select avoid empty option

Tags: material-ui

Having a Select component on material-ui which receives options as props. Is there any way to avoid an empty option?

Reason is, this select MUST always have a value on selected (empty/null not allowed)

```
<Select
    onChange={(e) => updateExisting(e, n)}
    value={n.partition_id}
    inputProps={{ name: 'partition_id' ,}}>
    <MenuItem value={0}></MenuItem>
    {sags.map(a => {
        return (
            <MenuItem key={a.id} value={a.id}>{a.name}</MenuItem>
    )})}
</Select>
```

in this case, `value={0}` is not valid and only any value received on sags is valid.

Comment: Figured out how to solve it. on componentWillReceiveProps i set a state with an id, then on the select i use value={this.state.select_id}

Comment: You should mark as answered ;)